# Is NGINX safe for webapps that usually rely on htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, drupal

First of all, you don't have to convince me that NGINX is good, I know that and want to use it for all web projects.

I was asked this question the other day, and didn't have a solid answer, as I haven't looked much at that specific situation.

**The Question, elaborated**
Old and new web software, such as Drupal and Wordpress, come with some `.htaccess`-files, and while there are plenty of example configs for nginx for them available with just a simple search.

- How can I assure clients that nginx is secure for Drupal and Wordpress respectively?
- How can the nginx configs out there cover such complex systems and keep them just as safe as with apache+htaccess?

I don't need complete answers here, but links to articles that tries to answer this or similar questions.

I want to convince some clients to move to nginx for the huge performance boost it would give them, but they need more proof that I have, in regards to security with systems that usually rely on htaccess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is an .htaccess file?

It's a *partial web server configuration file* that's dynamically parsed on each (applicable) request. It allows you to override certain aspects of the web server's behaviour on a per-directory basis by sprinkling configuration snippets in them.

Fundamentally it does nothing one central configuration file can't, it just decentralises that configuration and allows users to override that configuration without having direct access to the web server as such. That has proven very useful and popular in the shared-hosting model, where the host does not want to provide full access to the web server configuration and/or that would be impractical.

nginx fundamentally uses one configuration file only, but you can add to that by including other configuration files with the `include` directive, with which you could ultimately mimic a similar system. But nginx is also so ridiculously performant because it does *not* do dynamic configuration inclusion on a per-directory basis; that is a huge performance drain on every request in Apache. Any sane Apache configuration will disable .htaccess parsing to avoid that loss of performance, at which point there's no fundamental difference between it and nginx.

Even more fundamentally: what is a web server? It's a program that responds to HTTP requests with specific HTTP responses. Which response you get depends on the request you send. You can configure the web server to send specific responses to specific requests, based on a whole host of variables. Apache and nginx can equally be configured to respond to requests in the same way. As long as you do that, there's no difference in behaviour and thereby "security".

Comment: Do you know of a way to make sure that older .htaccess files buried god knows how deep inside a webapp's structure, gets found and properly "converted" to part of the sites nginx config? Doesn't have to be automated, just something that saves me time when planning to move an old webapp over.

Comment: No; a `find /path .htaccess` should reveal those files, from where you can manually convert them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, pretty sure I have enough information now to persuade most of the clients :)

Comment: Also, htaccess files are disabled by default in Apache these days, due to performance issues. When .htaccess files are enabled, the web server must check for it on every hit in every subdirectory from where it resides.